# Export installed software to csv from multiple remote systems

Tags: powershell

My script does (somewhat) what it's supposed to do if I need the information from the local PC.  I have it reaching to a txt file for a list of computers. The script will read the list and show "Processing:..." for the list of computers but the export only shows the local system.  Even if I remove my local PC from the txt file, the export to csv still only shows the local system.  It does create the correct columns and populates accordingly. I just need it to pull the data from remote systems as well.  Since the script will be used by multiple people, the variables allow the txt file and output file to be on their systems.

```
Function Export-InstalledSoftware {
    Process {
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -count 1 -quiet)
            {
            echo "Processing: $env:COMPUTERNAME"    
                Get-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*,HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* `
                    | Select-object @{n='ComputerName';e={$env:COMPUTERNAME}},@{n='DisplayName';e={$_.displayName}},@{n='Publisher';e={$_.Publisher}},@{n='DisplayVersion';e={$_.DisplayVersion}} `
                    | Sort displayName `
                    | Export-CSV C:\Users\$(get-content env:username)\Desktop\"SoftwareQuery_"$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)".csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
            }
        }
    }

Get-Content "C:\Users\$(get-content env:username)\Desktop\systems.txt" -readcount 1 | Export-InstalledSoftware
```

Comment: A script running on your local machine, `HKLM:\SOFTWARE` is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, which is (surprise) always the local machine where the script it running. If you want to query remote systems, you need a working method of remoting and authenticating - WinRM these days, and `Invoke-Command` to run your script remotely, or maybe a classic RPC remoting call via WMI, depends what's available and configured in your environment. Still "I have code and it doesn't work and I wish it worked differently" isn't really an on-topic, specific, answerable programming question.

Comment: I understand that... but I need the HKLM from a quantity of remote machines - which is why I scripted it that way.  If there is another way or better way, isn't that what we are all here for?  To help, to teach, to learn?  I'm relatively new at this and learning as I go.  Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: It'll take some scripting magic, but you can always try creating the PSDrive of HKEY_USERS, finding the user's SID, then looking at HKU:\<SID>\Software and printing a list of everything there.  It'll be like being able to remotely query HKCU, but you have to know the user sids.  It'll give you common names of software though, not anything definitive.  Using `Invoke-Command` or a remote WMI call are your better options.  I agree with @TessellatingHeckler.  Another alternative would be to use a remote management tool like SCCM or GPO to do this.